# How to populate error from child workflow to parent workflow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I got two step functions. Parent step function call Child step function and wait for result. It works as expected in happy scenario. But when Child step function's lambda throw error and failed. Parent step function only receive `States.TaskFailed` the detail error code from lambda is omitted. Is there a way to get that error out?

Here is my sample function:

```json
{
    "Comment": "Parent state machine",
    "StartAt": "CallChildAndWait",
    "States": {
        "CallChildAndWait": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync:2",
            "Parameters": {
                "Input":{
                    "Comment": "Pretent that my input goes here",
                    "AWS_STEP_FUNCTIONS_STARTED_BY_EXECUTION_ID.$": "$$.Execution.Id"
                },
                "StateMachineArn.$": "arn:child-state-machine-step-fn"
            },
            "End": true
        }
    }
}

{
    "Comment": "Child state machine",
    "StartAt": "DoSomethingAndReturn",
    "States": {
        "DoSomethingAndReturn": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
            "Parameters":{  
                "FunctionName":"MyFunction"
            },
            "End": true
        }
    }
}
```

and lambda function that throw error 50% chance

```js
class RandomError extends Error {
  name = 'RANDOM_ERROR'
  message = 'Just failed randomly'
}

export const handler = async (event) => {
  const dice = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
  
  if (dice >= 5) {
    throw new RandomError('Crashed');
  }
  
  return {success: true}
}
```

How do I get `RANDOM_ERROR` error code from parent step function Catch handler?
This is all I got from parent

```json
{
  "Error": "States.TaskFailed",
  "Cause": "A very big json string and RANDOM_ERROR no where to be found"
}
```

I could also do `waitForTaskToken` and report success failed directly from lambda but I tried to avoid that (since have to bundle aws-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can be catching the Lambda error in the Child state machine and building an object with all necessary information.

For example the Child can be:

```json
{
  "Comment": "Child state machine",
  "StartAt": "DoSomethingAndReturn",
  "States": {
    "DoSomethingAndReturn": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "MyFunction"
      },
      "End": true,
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "Next": "Pass",
          "ResultPath": "$.errorDetails"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Pass": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true,
      "Parameters": {
        "IsSuccessful": false,
        "Details.$": "$.errorDetails"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You catch the error, add all error details to input object using "ResultPath" in Catch. Then use Pass to build the final output object.

In the Parent then you can check IsSuccessful and make decisions based on that.

Comment: Yeah we end up doing this so child task guarantee to return result either success or failed. Thanks